# Need help solving a min-max fixed point equation

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, functional-equations, dynamic-programming, subgradient

I have the following fixed point equation: for all $p\in[0,1]$

$$V(p) = \min_{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in[0,1]}\max\{pr,(1-p)r,\beta\mathbb{E}_{a,y'}[V(f_{\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}(p,a,y'))]\}$$
where the expectation is given by
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_{a,y'}[V(f_{\lambda}(p,a,y'))]
&=(\gamma_1\lambda_1p + (1-\gamma_2)\lambda_2(1-p))V\left(\frac{\gamma_1\lambda_1p}{\gamma_1\lambda_1p + (1-\gamma_2)\lambda_2(1-p)}\right)\\
&+((1-\gamma_1)\lambda_1p + \gamma_2\lambda_2(1-p))V\left(\frac{(1-\gamma_1)\lambda_1p}{(1-\gamma_1)\lambda_1p + \gamma_2\lambda_2(1-p)}\right)\\
&+(\gamma_1(1-\lambda_2)(1-p) + (1-\gamma_2)(1-\lambda_1)p)V\left(\frac{\gamma_1(1-\lambda_2)(1-p)}{\gamma_1(1-\lambda_2)(1-p) + (1-\gamma_2)(1-\lambda_1)p)}\right)\\
&+((1-\gamma_1)(1-\lambda_2)(1-p) + \gamma_2(1-\lambda_1)p)V\left(\frac{(1-\gamma_1)(1-\lambda_2)(1-p)}{(1-\gamma_1)(1-\lambda_2)(1-p) + \gamma_2(1-\lambda_1)p}\right)\\
\end{align*}

where $r>0$, $\beta\in[0,1)$, and $\gamma_1,\gamma_2\in[0,1]$ are given.

I can use the fact that $V(\cdot)$ is convex in $p$. I can also prove that the expectation term, $\mathbb{E}_{a,y'}[V(f_{\lambda}(p,a,y'))]$, is convex in $p$ for any $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$.

**Question:** Any ideas on how I would go about solving for $V(\cdot)$? It seems like it may be possible to get somewhere analytically due to the nice properties of $V$ but even a numerical procedure would suffice.

---

**Attempt:** Based on Paul's comment, the fixed point equation can be written as:

$$V(p) = \max\{pr,(1-p)r,\beta\min_{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in[0,1]}\mathbb{E}_{a,y'}[V(f_{\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}(p,a,y'))]\}$$

but I'm not too sure how to represent the solution of the inner minimization problem, $\min_{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in[0,1]}\mathbb{E}_{a,y'}[V(f_{\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}(p,a,y'))]$, in terms of $V(\cdot)$.

I tried to draw a picture of what $V(p)$ might look like. Let $g(p) = \beta\min_{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in[0,1]}\mathbb{E}_{a,y'}[V(f_{\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}(p,a,y'))]$.

[image]

If $\beta$ is small enough, then it appears the solution of the fixed point is $V(p)=\max\{pr,(1-p)r\}$, but I am seeking a solution for all values of $\beta\in[0,1)$. Note that even though $g(p)$ is convex, the shape of $V(p)$ may be complex (it's possible to draw a convex function $g(p)$ that intersects the lines $pr$, $(1-p)r$ at most 4 times).

**Update:** I'm not actually sure if Paul's suggestion holds in general. Wouldn't the minimizer $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ depend on $\pi$?

Comment: Since only the third element in the max set is dependent on $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, the min and max can be exchanged. You may also be able to use the fact that $V(p) \ge r/2$ for all $p$

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks! Do you mean that I can bring the minimum into the third argument of the maximum? Do you think Lagrangian duality would be useful for the next step?

Comment: Since the first two arguments do not vary with $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, yes. I'm not particularly familiar with Lagrangian duality, so I cannot comment. I was just giving a couple things I noticed. If I actually had a solution path, I would put in an answer.